# Derive the following expression for the three touchpoints of the incircle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle_\text{ABC}$ be a triangle in $\mathbb{E}^2$. Additionaly, there are three points $\text{D}\in \overline{\text{AB}}$, $\text{E}\in \overline{\text{BC}}$ and $\text{F}\in \overline{\text{AC}}$, which are the touchpoints of the incircle of $\triangle_\text{ABC}$ with $\text{AB}$, $\text{BC}$ and $\text{AC}$. Also, let $\sigma$ be half the circumference of $\triangle_\text{ABC}$: $\sigma:=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. Show that the touch points can be expressed as followed:

$$ \text{D}=\frac{\sigma-b}{c}\text{A}-\frac{\sigma-a}{c}\text{B}$$ $$\text{E}=\frac{\sigma-c}{a}\text{B}-\frac{\sigma-b}{a}\text{C} $$

$$\text{F}=\frac{\sigma-c}{b}\text{A}-\frac{\sigma-a}{b}\text{C}$$.

Here is also an picture as an example to show you which points I mean.
[image: Touchpoints of incircle.]

The incircle is the biggest possible circle that can be inscribed into the triangle, where the incircle can be created by finding the intersection of all three angle bisectors and then finding the lines which are perpendicular to an edge and runs through the middle point of the circle (which is the intersection of all three angel bisectors).

I'm currently studying for my geometry exam for university and I am currently look at old exams, where the solutions are unfortunately not provided. It's an interesting problem where you need to derive the touching points just by knowing the edges and the coordinates of the vertices. Unfortunately I really don't know where to start here so any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Is the context I added sufficient? I will post progress as soon as I think that I actually made some progress...

Comment: Imo it is fine now

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. If $$A = (x_1, y_1), B=(x_2,y_2), C= (x_3,y_3)$$ then the coordinates of incenter or point $$M = (\frac{ax_1+bx_2+cx_3}{a+b+c}, \frac{ay_1+by_2+cy_3}{a+b+c})$$ Additionally, $$A(△ABC)=\frac{1}{2}×r×(a+b+c)$$